# LINQ to Dictionary with AND condition

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` called recsList. The following two queries check for any instance of certain values in two separate keys in each Dictionary in recsList.

I need to combine these queries with an AND condition so that I get a true if the same Dictionary has both conditions met.

```
bool multipleCodesFound = recsList.SelectMany(a => a)
    .Where(x => x.Key.Equals("multCodesFound")).Any((y => y.Value == (true).ToString()));
bool doubleCRLFFound = recsList.SelectMany(a => a)
    .Where(x => x.Key.Equals("CountofCRLF")).Any(y => int.Parse(y.Value) > 1);
```

Comment: IMO, use a third bool and do the `and` between the two first results, instead of making a ugly huge LINQ query.

Comment: Problem is that that will give me the answer that the recsList contains a Dictionary with one (or both) of the conditions and another Dictionary with the other condition (or both). I need to be sure the same Dictionary has both.

Comment: Why are you using `.Any()` and, not adding that clause into `Where`?

Comment: I reasoned it out that I would get a list of Dictionaries with the one key I needed and then see if any of them met the condition. I'm pretty new at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you want. This should also be more efficient than what you are doing above because your approach iterates over every key of every dictionary until it finds a match (nullifying the efficiency benefits of using dictionaries):

```
bool isAMatch = recsList.Any(d => d.ContainsKey("multCodesFound")          &&
                                  d.ContainsKey("CountofCRLF")             &&
                                  d["multCodesFound"] == bool.TrueString   &&
                                  int.Parse(d["CountofCRLF"]) > 1);
```

As ytoledano correcly points out, using `ContainsKey` followed by a dictionary retrieval is inefficient because it requires two lookups. To avoid that performance penalty, you could use the approach below, although I'd say in cases like this it may be worth taking the performance hit in order to have the more concise code above:

```
bool isAMatch = recsList.Any(d => {
    string val;
    return d.TryGetValue("multCodesFound", out val) &&
           val == bool.TrueString                   &&
           d.TryGetValue("CountofCRLF", out val)    &&
           int.Parse(val) > 1;
});
```

Comment: I was over thinking this one.

Comment: Isn't it better to do a TryGetValue to avoid duplicate lookups on the dictionary?

Comment: @ytoledano I don't know if the difference is big enough to worry about most of the time, and avoiding the performance penalty requires uglier code, but you are right. I've added an alternative approach with `TryGetValue()`.

Comment: I was thinking of posting the solution with `TryGetValue` but you were faster. Addition: You could also do: `string value; bool isAMatch = recsList.Any(d => 
    d.TryGetValue("multCodesFound", out value) &&
           value == "True"                            &&
           d.TryGetValue("CountofCRLF", out value)    &&
           int.Parse(value) > 1
);` Instead of `"True"` you can also do `bool.TrueString`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, there is that option, but I think it's good policy to avoid predicates with side-effects as much as possible. I do, however, like the idea of using a single string variable, so I will borrow that. :) I'll also use your `bool.TrueString` suggestion. I didn't know such a constant existed.

Comment: Then **if** it is known that the value corresponding to the first key is always either `"True"` or `"False"`, a possibility is to use `... && bool.Parse(val) && ...`. It is presumably a bit slower, but it looks more like the condition on the other (`int`) value.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, and `bool.Parse()` would also handle account for casing inconsistencies and whitespace. On the other hand, the performance benefit and avoiding the possibility of a `FormatException` are benefits of using `val == bool.TrueValue`, so it's a bit of a toss-up.